# ML.NET Schema mismatch: expected VarVector<Byte> got Vector<Byte>

Tags: c#, schema, ml.net

I have been attempting to modify an ML.NET tutorial on Image Classification and have been running into a schema mismatch problem where the model is expecting a VarVector and it is getting passed a Vector.

The original example creates an IDataView with a column named "ImagePath" filled with image paths and then generates an "Image" column of byte data using the MLContext.Transforms.LoadRawImageBytes(). The resulting IDataView is then fed to a Multiclassification.Trainers.ImageClassification() object. It is very straightforward.

I am looking to generalize it to involve a bit more image preprocessing. I would like for the preprocessing pipeline to reduce the image resolution and then also crop the image to the correct size prior to feeding it to the ImageClassification() trainer. It follows the same flow as the example but changes the processing pipeline to use the LoadImages(), ResizeImage(), and ExtractPixels() estimators in the image processing pipeline. Below is a snippet of code that I am working with.

```
    // Fill an IDataView with the Label and ImagePath information:
    // The ImageData class is defined for this purpose and it is just:
    // 
    //  public class ImageData {
    //       public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    //       public string Label { get; set; }
    //  }
    // 
    // Create a bunch of image names and their labels into a list of ImageData objects.
    IEnumerable<ImageData> images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: assetsRelativePath, 
                                                            useFolderNameAsLabel: true);
    IDataView imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);

    // Define the preprocessing pipeline to:
    // 1. Map the Label to a unique key
    // 2. Load the image data using the ImagePath column
    // 3. Reduce the resolution of the image data
    // 4. Crop the reduced resolution image data
    // 5. Transform the image data from type "Image" to a byte array.
    var preprocessingPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(
                    inputColumnName: "Label",
                    outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(
                    inputColumnName: "ImagePath",
                    outputColumnName: "RawImage",
                    imageFolder: assetsRelativePath))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(
                    inputColumnName: "RawImage",
                    outputColumnName: "ResReduxImage",
                    imageWidth: 512,
                    imageHeight: 459,
                    resizing: Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(
                    inputColumnName: "ResReduxImage",
                    outputColumnName: "CroppedImage",
                    imageWidth: 512,
                    imageHeight: 459,
                    resizing: Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.IsoCrop,
                    cropAnchor: Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingEstimator.Anchor.Center))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(
                    inputColumnName: "CroppedImage",
                    outputColumnName: "Image",
                    outputAsFloatArray: false,
                    colorsToExtract: ImagePixelExtractingEstimator.ColorBits.Red));

     // Transform the raw ImageData into the TransformedData that the Model will train on
     IDataView preProcessedData = preprocessingPipeline.Fit(imageData).Transform(imageData);

     // Partition the data set for training and validation
     TrainTestData trainSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data: preProcessedData, testFraction: 0.4);
     TrainTestData validationTestSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainSplit.TestSet);

     IDataView trainSet = trainSplit.TrainSet;
     IDataView validationSet = validationTestSplit.TrainSet;
     IDataView testSet = validationTestSplit.TestSet;

     var classifierOptions = new ImageClassificationTrainer.Options()
     {
          FeatureColumnName = "Image",
          LabelColumnName = "LabelAsKey",
          ValidationSet = validationSet,
          Arch = ImageClassificationTrainer.Architecture.ResnetV2101,
          MetricsCallback = (metrics) => Console.WriteLine(metrics),
          TestOnTrainSet = false,
          ReuseTrainSetBottleneckCachedValues = true,
          ReuseValidationSetBottleneckCachedValues = true,
          WorkspacePath=workspaceRelativePath
     };

     var trainingPipeline = 
           mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(classifierOptions)
           .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

     // When I call Fit() in the next line of code, the following runtime error occurs: 
     // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for feature column 'Image': 
     // expected VarVector<Byte>, got Vector<Byte> Parameter name: inputSchema'
     ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainSet);
```

I am stumped about the VarVector and Vector mismatch. I have tried the following over the past two days with no success:

- to define a custom DataViewSchema to pass to the transform
- to define a custom DataView by deriving from IDataView
- to define a custom mapping using a CustomMapping<> to change the type

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to get myself out of this jam? I would really like to avoid reading in an image, preprocessing it, writing it to file, then calling the original LoadRawImageBytes() function. I don't want that extra filesystem work.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to make this work. The issue here was that the underlying types were correct but the schema was wrong. I was able to solve my issue with a CustomMapping and some attribute magic.See [CustomMapping documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.custommappingcatalog.custommapping?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_CustomMappingCatalog_CustomMapping__2_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_System_Action___0___1__System_String_Microsoft_ML_Data_SchemaDefinition_Microsoft_ML_Data_SchemaDefinition_) for how the CustomMapping works.

The corrected code snippet is below.

```
    // SOMEWHERE OUTSIDE OF THE FUNCTION DEFINE:
    // Define a class to represent the input column type for the custom transform
    class InputData 
    {
        [VectorType(1)] // attribute specifies vector type of known length
        public VBuffer<Byte> Image1; // the VBuffer<> type actually represents the data
    }

    // Define a class to represent the output column type for the custom transform
    class OutputData 
    {
        // THE MAGICAL FIX: attribute specifies vector type of unknown length (i.e. VarVector)
        [VectorType()]
        public VBuffer<Byte> Image; // the VBuffer<> type actually represents the data
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // INSIDE THE FUNCTION THAT WILL DO THE TRAINING
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Fill an IDataView with the Label and ImagePath information:
    // The ImageData class is defined for this purpose and it is just:
    // 
    //  public class ImageData {
    //       public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    //       public string Label { get; set; }
    //  }
    // 
    // Create a bunch of image names and their labels into a list of ImageData objects.
    IEnumerable<ImageData> images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: assetsRelativePath, 
                                                            useFolderNameAsLabel: true);
    IDataView imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);

    // Define the preprocessing pipeline to:
    // 1. Map the Label to a unique key
    // 2. Load the image data using the ImagePath column
    // 3. Reduce the resolution of the image data
    // 4. Crop the reduced resolution image data
    // 5. Transform the image data from type "Image" to a byte array.
    var preprocessingPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(
                    inputColumnName: "Label",
                    outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(
                    inputColumnName: "ImagePath",
                    outputColumnName: "RawImage",
                    imageFolder: assetsRelativePath))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(
                    inputColumnName: "RawImage",
                    outputColumnName: "ResReduxImage",
                    imageWidth: 512,
                    imageHeight: 459,
                    resizing: Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(
                    inputColumnName: "ResReduxImage",
                    outputColumnName: "CroppedImage",
                    imageWidth: 512,
                    imageHeight: 459,
                    resizing: Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.IsoCrop,
                    cropAnchor: Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Image.ImageResizingEstimator.Anchor.Center))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(
                    inputColumnName: "CroppedImage",
                    outputColumnName: "Image1",
                    outputAsFloatArray: false,
                    colorsToExtract: ImagePixelExtractingEstimator.ColorBits.Red));

     // Transform the raw ImageData into the TransformedData that the Model will train on
     IDataView preProcessedData = 
           preprocessingPipeline.Fit(imageData).Transform(imageData);

     // Create an action representing the custom transform...
     // The data itself does not need to be changed at all, so this is just an 
     // identity transform
     Action<InputData, OutputData> convertVecType 
               = (input, output) => output.Image = input.Image1;
 
     var convertTypePipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CustomMapping(convertVecType, 
                                                                 "convertVecType");
     preProcessedData = 
              convertTypePipeline.Fit(preProcessedData).Transform(preProcessedData);

     // Partition the data set for training and validation
     TrainTestData trainSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data: preProcessedData, testFraction: 0.4);
     TrainTestData validationTestSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainSplit.TestSet);

     IDataView trainSet = trainSplit.TrainSet;
     IDataView validationSet = validationTestSplit.TrainSet;
     IDataView testSet = validationTestSplit.TestSet;

     var classifierOptions = new ImageClassificationTrainer.Options()
     {
          FeatureColumnName = "Image",
          LabelColumnName = "LabelAsKey",
          ValidationSet = validationSet,
          Arch = ImageClassificationTrainer.Architecture.ResnetV2101,
          MetricsCallback = (metrics) => Console.WriteLine(metrics),
          TestOnTrainSet = false,
          ReuseTrainSetBottleneckCachedValues = true,
          ReuseValidationSetBottleneckCachedValues = true,
          WorkspacePath=workspaceRelativePath
     };

     var trainingPipeline = 
           mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(classifierOptions)
           .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

     // When I call Fit() in the next line of code, the following runtime error occurs: 
     // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for feature column 'Image': 
     // expected VarVector<Byte>, got Vector<Byte> Parameter name: inputSchema'
     ITransformer trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainSet);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the post and the answer! I've bumped into the exact same issue.
One question though...
Your fix managed to get me through in the training phase but now I'm always getting NaN accuracy at the end of the training. I'm only applying a resize and extracting the pixels.
If I remove the resize and pixel extraction and go back using LoadImagesRawBytes, everything works fine again. Any idea by any chance? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been bumping my head on this for two years. I really wanted to give the vector size at runtime. Finally, I found an elegant way to handle this.
The short answer is, create an input schema based on your InputData class, modify the proper columns to contain the proper vector size, and then pass this schema in on DataView creation.

A more detailed version is as follows:

I start with my ModelInput class that has properties like this. (It also has functions to load images and get the data...)

```
public class ModelInput
{
    //This is just used for internal identification
    public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
    //An array of loaded bytes if needed.
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; private set; }
    //An array of floats that took the ImageBytes and normalized them to floats. Normally the values are between 0 and 1.
    public float[] ImageFloats { get; private set; }
    //This is just used for internal identification
    public string ImageName { get; private set; }
    //The label
    public string Label { get; private set; }
    //An array of vector dimensions like [150,150,3]. This is set when the image is loaded and 
    //converted to ImageFloats
    public int[] VectorDimensions { get; private set; }
}
```

I go ahead and load the image, convert it to a 3 channel byte array, and then to a float array using SixLabors image tools. In the process, I get the image dimensions and save it in the VectorDimensions.
I strip out all the image prepocessing in the model pipeline and do it in the ModelInput class so the ML.Net model expects an array of floats.

I load the first ModelInput which will populate the VectorDimensions field.
Then i use that to get a SchemaDef

```
public SchemaDefinition GetSchemaDefinition()
{
        var inputSchemaDefinition = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(ModelInput), SchemaDefinition.Direction.Both);
        inputSchemaDefinition["ImageFloats"].ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(NumberDataViewType.Single, VectorDimensions);
        inputSchemaDefinition["ImageBytes"].ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(NumberDataViewType.Byte, VectorDimensions);
        return inputSchemaDefinition;
}
```

Load your model like normal.

Create the IEnumerable from the files desired

```
    internal IEnumerable<ModelInput> LoadData(string folderPath, bool shouldShuffle)
    {
        
        var images = LoadFileNames(folderPath, shouldShuffle);
        
        foreach (var item in images)
        {
//You can figure out how to load the image into ModelInput and create
//the byte or float arrays, and fill in the Label and VectorDimension fields
//I leave my code here as an example to give you ideas.
            //var options = new ModelInputOptions(item, batchOptions.LabelClass, batchOptions.ResnetType,
                //batchOptions.ResizeType, batchOptions.ChannelsDesired, batchOptions.Offset);
            ModelInput modelInput = new ModelInput();
            //You need to do something here to load the image and fill in the properties.
            //modelInput.LoadData(options);
            //Yield return is important here. This makes the images lazy loading.
            yield return modelInput;

        }

    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads file names and applies and ordering
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="folder">the folder that contains all the categories and images</param>
    /// <param name="sortByFilename">false if the filename is used as the sort key, true to randomly shuffle</param>
    /// <returns>A sorted array of file names</returns>
    private string[] LoadFileNames(string folder, bool shouldShuffle)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*",
           searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (files == null || !files.Any())
        {
            return new string[0];
        }
        

        if (shouldShuffle)
        {
            return Shuffle(files.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            //Use this if you want to order them by image name
            //return files.OrderBy(x=>Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
            return files.Select(x=>Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray();
        }
    }

    private string[] Shuffle(List<string> fileNames)
    {
      
        var result = fileNames.ToDictionary(k => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).OrderBy(k=>k.Key);
       return result.Select(k => k.Value).ToArray();
    }
```

Load your images. This is a lazy load due to the yield return.

```
var images = LoadData(folderPath, shouldShuffle);
```

Here's the magic you've been waiting for. Pass the images and the modified schema to the dataview

```
IDataView imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images, schema);
```

Everything should work!!!!