# Generic import and run of ML onnx model using ML.Net

Tags: c#, dynamic, ml.net

I am trying to figure out how to create code to import an ONNX model with one input, being a flat array of floats. However at compile time I do not know the length of the array. This stops me at creating this code. I use this statement:

mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<OnnxInput, OnnxOutput>

Where the class OnnxInput contains the property, witn an attribute specifying the length of the array

```
[VectorType(1024)]
[ColumnName("input1")]
public float[] data { get; set; }
```

But I do not know the length in general, so the number 1024 is in general wrong.
I have tried to looking at using dynamic objects in C#, but it seems to support only objects, not types. Maybe there is a better way to use the "ML.Net" to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tough to provide an answer because many times how you go about it depends on the model you're using. In general though, there are two methods you might try:

1. Dynamic size - You can do that by using `VectorType()` attribute instead of `VectorType(n)` where N are the dimensions of your vector.
2. Fixed size - Usually as mentioned earlier, although not annotated in the ONNX model, it's likely in the model paper or somewhere similar this information is available. For example, there are some models like BERT that limit the number of tokens as input to [512](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478859/why-does-bert-has-a-limitation-of-only-allowing-the-maximum-length-of-the-input). With that in mind, you can do what you've done today and use `VectorType(512)` which just means, your inputs will always be 512. Any text that's longer, you truncate and any text that's shorter you'll pad (Add empty / filler values).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, good to have a second opinion on this. I will set this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment, but I have to have 50 reputation first.
Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311274/16802462 to see how to set vector length at runtime. It is as simple as setting the length in the schema and then passing that schema on to the model at creation.